# Going from long to wide format in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data set of juvenile fish lengths collected in 1992 at different sites. I have also assigned each value a uniqueID (due to previous errors while using the pivot_wider function). The data is as follows:

```
df<-structure(list(year = c(92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 
92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L
), site = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 
28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
31L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
33L, 33L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
"5", "10", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "32", "33", "34", "35", "40", "41", "46", "50", "51", "52", 
"53", "57", "58", "65", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "75", 
"76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "84", "85"), class = "factor"), 
    length = c(64L, 71L, 70L, 64L, 53L, 55L, 53L, 61L, 74L, 62L, 
    66L, 65L, 57L, 66L, 71L, 65L, 74L, 68L, 70L, 67L, 73L, 67L, 
    71L, 45L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 96L, 133L, 72L, 127L, 69L, 66L, 
    68L, 142L, 52L, 68L, 62L, 67L, 65L, 147L, 167L, 157L, 145L, 
    136L, 128L, 146L, 144L, 129L, 121L, 130L, 129L, 200L, 124L, 
    101L, 86L, 83L, 90L, 59L, 61L, 88L, 57L, 56L, 59L, 67L, 58L, 
    47L, 59L, 43L, 89L, 65L, 71L, 71L, 69L, 62L, 68L, 65L, 60L, 
    61L, 63L, 62L, 61L, 43L, 64L, 67L, 85L, 35L, 176L, 197L, 
    66L, 46L, 44L, 43L, 42L, 45L, 45L, 178L, 77L, 40L, 66L, 42L, 
    62L, 47L, 71L, 42L, 74L, 60L, 58L, 45L, 49L, 50L, 65L, 46L, 
    60L, 48L, 36L, 40L, 46L, 38L, 46L, 43L, 37L, 46L, 51L, 57L, 
    69L, 69L, 41L, 44L, 42L, 63L, 47L, 44L, 43L, 47L, 49L, 37L, 
    47L, 46L, 40L, 44L, 45L, 38L, 41L, 47L, 47L, 54L, 37L, 43L, 
    47L, 42L, 39L, 39L, 44L, 39L, 45L, 47L, 38L, 42L, 65L, 41L, 
    44L, 38L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 36L, 43L, 48L, 
    44L, 40L, 44L, 44L, 41L, 39L, 40L, 36L, 42L, 41L, 43L, 38L, 
    39L, 44L, 40L, 47L, 43L, 50L, 44L, 45L, 36L, 46L, 43L, 46L, 
    38L, 39L, 49L, 40L, 232L, 222L, 131L, 154L, 151L, 75L, 44L, 
    40L, 44L, 44L, 43L, 46L, 223L, 198L, 167L, 146L, 84L, 45L, 
    50L, 42L, 40L, 47L, 40L, 45L, 55L, 40L, 51L, 42L, 46L, 43L, 
    46L, 40L, 42L, 45L, 50L, 40L, 44L, 48L, 44L, 42L, 56L, 43L, 
    46L, 39L, 40L, 46L, 41L, 40L, 37L, 49L, 46L, 40L, 43L, 42L, 
    43L, 46L, 40L, 42L, 45L, 50L, 40L, 44L, 48L, 44L, 42L, 56L, 
    43L, 46L, 39L, 40L, 46L, 41L, 40L, 37L, 49L, 46L, 40L, 43L, 
    42L, 45L, 44L, 40L, 44L, 34L, 220L, 184L, 155L, 152L, 167L, 
    163L, 157L, 138L, 130L, 98L, 98L, 137L, 92L, 85L, 82L, 89L, 
    85L, 216L, 220L, 205L, 143L, 147L, 150L, 152L, 163L, 132L, 
    156L, 157L, 147L, 145L, 132L, 91L, 90L, 81L, 86L, 89L, 84L, 
    84L, 134L, 45L, 205L, 157L, 163L, 166L, 134L, 140L, 87L, 
    66L, 95L, 85L, 89L, 90L, 96L, 91L, 87L, 83L, 91L, 80L, 88L, 
    88L, 82L, 60L, 43L, 37L, 43L, 176L, 182L, 142L, 146L, 147L, 
    92L, 97L, 140L, 100L, 94L, 91L, 90L, 87L, 92L, 92L, 86L, 
    84L, 89L, 51L, 48L, 49L, 42L, 90L, 145L, 87L, 93L, 135L, 
    92L, 90L, 83L, 87L, 86L, 89L, 79L, 95L, 91L, 96L, 93L, 84L, 
    47L, 45L, 37L, 89L, 102L, 89L, 84L, 163L, 131L, 94L, 95L, 
    93L, 80L, 87L, 75L, 46L, 50L, 82L, 96L, 68L, 46L, 41L, 51L, 
    36L, 48L, 94L, 87L, 82L, 66L, 95L, 82L, 67L, 46L, 40L, 64L, 
    46L, 41L, 45L, 41L, 232L, 150L, 173L, 155L, 152L, 155L, 96L, 
    141L, 132L, 93L, 48L, 90L, 174L, 152L, 152L, 133L, 158L, 
    139L, 93L, 90L, 77L, 73L, 155L, 97L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 73L, 
    79L, 67L, 65L, 74L, 46L, 79L, 75L, 88L, 75L, 90L, 47L, 51L, 
    49L, 81L, 78L, 71L, 83L, 74L, 82L, 85L, 80L, 77L, 81L, 77L, 
    80L, 68L, 80L, 91L, 82L, 75L, 84L, 79L, 42L, 83L, 90L, 89L, 
    88L, 85L, 95L, 87L, 92L, 83L, 90L, 88L, 85L, 78L, 79L, 88L, 
    76L, 84L, 87L, 79L, 82L, 90L, 67L, 83L, 80L, 84L, 88L, 84L, 
    90L, 86L, 85L, 79L, 81L, 80L, 82L, 84L, 77L, 92L, 88L, 90L, 
    88L, 81L, 91L, 87L, 88L, 80L, 90L, 91L, 87L, 84L, 87L, 82L, 
    76L, 85L, 75L, 73L, 87L, 89L, 77L, 96L, 82L, 82L, 89L, 86L, 
    84L, 84L, 92L, 91L, 86L, 87L, 93L, 77L, 83L, 82L, 93L, 87L, 
    86L, 76L, 82L, 68L, 91L, 92L, 76L, 94L, 88L, 86L, 98L, 91L, 
    84L, 83L, 100L, 95L, 79L, 98L, 89L, 88L, 79L, 84L, 93L, 87L, 
    103L, 92L, 85L, 94L, 83L, 97L, 96L, 83L, 91L, 73L, 84L, 87L, 
    96L, 79L, 96L, 69L, 85L, 95L, 91L, 89L, 86L, 77L, 80L, 54L, 
    153L, 90L, 80L, 139L, 94L, 89L, 91L, 98L, 95L, 87L, 91L, 
    86L, 94L, 86L, 92L, 92L, 98L, 82L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 84L, 
    86L, 85L, 96L, 83L, 83L, 139L, 97L, 80L, 85L, 86L, 150L, 
    89L, 78L, 85L, 80L, 93L, 95L, 93L, 92L, 79L, 168L, 96L, 98L, 
    87L, 91L, 103L, 86L, 93L, 90L, 80L, 84L, 84L, 41L, 152L, 
    85L, 91L, 89L, 83L, 87L, 87L, 89L, 84L, 64L, 89L, 83L, 90L, 
    84L, 90L, 94L, 87L, 78L, 83L, 99L, 95L, 90L, 89L, 96L, 96L, 
    92L, 99L, 82L, 80L, 84L, 94L, 74L, 70L, 111L, 129L, 141L, 
    135L, 88L, 78L, 64L, 68L, 58L, 67L, 50L, 57L, 50L, 170L, 
    139L, 172L, 142L, 121L, 121L, 144L, 155L, 136L, 131L, 125L, 
    127L, 133L, 124L, 73L, 83L, 44L, 52L, 44L, 39L, 43L, 48L, 
    47L, 52L, 46L, 47L, 50L, 172L, 133L, 93L, 128L, 244L, 252L, 
    150L, 162L, 150L, 106L, 95L, 98L, 84L, 108L, 48L, 47L, 84L, 
    136L, 49L, 47L, 131L, 73L, 70L, 54L, 59L, 52L, 55L, 48L, 
    55L, 45L, 222L, 238L, 40L, 40L, 43L, 45L, 67L, 47L, 50L, 
    41L, 61L, 54L, 43L, 42L, 89L, 43L, 42L, 48L, 64L, 55L, 40L, 
    52L, 46L, 49L, 46L, 49L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 176L, 154L, 97L, 
    83L, 97L, 132L, 88L, 95L, 98L, 82L, 81L, 92L, 96L, 89L, 63L, 
    90L, 93L, 82L, 97L, 93L, 100L, 85L, 78L, 85L, 72L, 73L, 62L, 
    62L, 60L, 58L, 128L, 98L, 87L, 96L, 56L, 86L, 87L, 78L, 58L, 
    73L, 55L, 54L, 62L, 46L, 85L, 193L, 140L, 97L, 95L, 87L, 
    40L, 208L, 210L, 146L, 46L, 206L, 40L, 262L, 145L, 52L, 72L, 
    49L, 85L, 70L, 47L, 93L, 69L, 65L, 54L, 60L, 46L, 44L, 48L, 
    56L, 58L, 49L, 42L, 52L, 42L, 50L, 51L, 50L, 53L, 42L, 48L, 
    49L, 45L, 45L, 49L, 42L, 47L, 60L, 51L, 53L, 46L, 49L, 46L, 
    56L, 57L, 57L, 48L, 52L, 49L, 50L, 46L, 56L, 62L, 51L, 46L, 
    50L, 46L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 46L, 51L, 48L, 42L, 48L, 42L, 
    47L, 43L, 55L, 50L, 44L, 46L, 52L, 46L, 44L, 45L, 53L, 53L, 
    56L, 57L, 45L, 42L, 41L, 55L, 50L, 51L, 50L, 47L, 51L, 45L, 
    280L, 192L, 185L, 150L, 183L, 150L, 189L, 211L, 159L, 134L, 
    134L, 138L, 132L, 136L, 145L, 125L, 147L, 149L, 161L, 126L, 
    44L, 142L, 148L, 138L, 154L, 135L, 150L, 134L, 152L, 128L, 
    233L, 188L, 155L, 137L, 121L, 148L, 138L, 240L, 214L, 163L, 
    143L, 149L, 127L, 115L, 156L, 124L, 132L, 166L, 159L, 152L, 
    95L, 171L, 154L, 142L, 170L, 155L, 140L, 163L, 123L, 139L, 
    111L, 148L, 142L, 149L, 137L, 154L, 183L, 136L, 207L, 138L, 
    155L, 160L, 148L, 150L, 141L, 137L, 210L, 198L, 149L, 212L, 
    240L, 222L, 171L, 165L, 187L, 177L, 167L, 139L, 137L, 103L, 
    122L, 127L, 149L, 154L, 156L, 137L, 145L, 174L, 144L, 127L, 
    124L, 96L, 168L, 163L, 136L, 136L, 124L, 128L, 192L, 169L, 
    192L, 163L, 177L, 133L, 155L, 169L, 135L, 158L, 145L, 154L, 
    132L, 152L, 136L, 126L, 116L, 183L, 157L, 155L, 141L, 145L, 
    203L, 160L, 146L, 152L, 182L, 157L, 149L, 164L, 142L, 160L, 
    183L, 127L, 150L, 123L, 128L, 154L, 126L, 127L, 133L, 105L, 
    135L, 117L, 131L, 150L, 121L, 258L, 278L, 243L, 241L, 222L, 
    110L, 155L, 149L, 159L, 155L, 159L, 152L, 134L, 133L, 198L, 
    164L, 138L, 127L, 156L, 141L, 129L, 135L, 153L, 148L, 136L, 
    133L, 158L, 137L, 133L, 132L, 117L, 134L, 150L, 145L, 145L, 
    135L, 150L, 157L, 145L, 136L, 127L, 133L, 121L, 143L, 134L, 
    255L, 126L, 137L, 201L, 182L, 150L, 118L, 157L, 160L, 143L, 
    150L, 142L, 194L, 186L, 156L, 151L, 177L, 155L, 128L, 128L, 
    145L, 133L, 130L, 121L, 125L, 135L, 147L, 121L, 135L, 167L, 
    155L, 148L, 144L, 137L, 135L, 150L, 162L, 151L, 156L, 151L, 
    160L, 166L, 150L, 122L, 146L, 152L, 162L, 162L, 122L, 144L, 
    147L, 145L, 142L, 150L, 145L, 121L, 137L, 117L, 140L, 142L, 
    134L, 140L, 134L, 131L, 136L, 116L, 135L, 127L, 129L, 185L, 
    46L, 220L, 142L, 152L, 127L, 45L, 47L, 45L, 54L, 51L, 56L, 
    49L, 49L, 58L, 49L, 51L, 45L, 47L, 44L, 69L, 57L, 48L, 52L, 
    60L, 40L, 51L, 46L, 43L, 49L, 43L, 47L, 45L, 56L, 46L, 48L, 
    46L, 49L, 48L, 50L, 66L, 49L, 59L, 47L, 59L, 50L, 43L, 53L, 
    48L, 56L, 44L, 52L, 42L, 51L, 44L, 51L, 53L, 40L, 50L, 50L, 
    34L, 48L, 51L, 51L, 46L, 47L, 53L, 32L), uniqueID = 1:1282), row.names = c(NA, 
-1282L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to transform this data from long to wide format. I have been trying to do this by using:

```
df1<- df %>% group_by(length) %>% pivot_wider(names_from=site, values_from=length) %>% select(-uniqueID)
```

It gives me an output, but it has a lot of NA's. How do I make it look like [table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72ntO.png) and not [table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acJuf.png)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pivot` functions ignore `group_by`.

Comment: Do you think you could illustrate the question with a smaller example than 1200+ rows? It would be great to work with 9-row example as in your `table1` and `table2` pictures. In that example, can you explain why the rows get matched up like they do? In table1 picture, why does `site10 = 64` occur in the same row as `site3 = 62`, and not, say, `site3 = 66` or `site3 = 65`? Within a particular year, is there anything in the input data to indicate which `site3` values should be in the same row as particular `site10` values? Do you care how they get lined up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need an `ID` for each combination of `year` and `site`. Please test the following to see if this is what you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
  select(-uniqueID) %>%
  group_by(year, site) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=site, values_from=length)
```